# how to compute bergman kernel

Tags: harmonic-analysis, several-complex-variables

i have a question to determin if the asyptotic expansion of Bergman kernel has a log term.  Is there anyone can show me is there any general way to tell?

Comment: Bergman kernel for what kinds of domain?

Comment: Please put a little effort into making this question understandable.  We have no knowledge about your situation here, although many of us do have knowledge of the Bergman kernel.

Comment: sorry for late response. for example if the domain is defined in $\mathbb{C}^3$ by the function $|z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2|+|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^2\leq1$

Answer (score 3):

This is the so called minimal ball (up to a factor). Its Bergman kernel is given in the paper by Oeljeklaus, Pflug, Youssfi or see the book by Jarnicki Pflug: Invariant distances...., second edition.